# Run server program and allow user to attach to it using SSH

Tags: ssh, tmux, gnu-screen, remote

What I'm trying to do is run a program at startup (a game server in this case, started using systemd) and allow a specific user to remotely "attach" to it using SSH. Currently I have it set up to start the program in a detached tmux session and for the login shell for that user I'm using a script that simply runs the command `tmux a`. So when the user connects using SSH they are immediately attached to that game server's console and they can type in commands and see the output for that program. The problem with this approach is that they can now simply do ctrl+b and `:new-session bash` in tmux and they will gain access to the system. I want them to only be able to access the game server's console and not start any other programs. Something like a very stripped-down tmux client that doesn't have any commands and only allows the user to interact with the program it's attached to. Does anything like this exist?